# shared_ptr with QThreadPool

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, threadpool, shared-ptr

I am currently using shared pointer with QThreadPool for a multi-threaded application. However I am experiencing crashes when the threads finishes computation.

Assume Class A is inherited from QRunnable and when passing in the shared pointer as argument, it updates its class variable. Here is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<VariableType> variable = boost::make_shared<VariableType>();
    variable->Update_One_InternalVariable(1); // just updating a class variable inside VariableType

    Class* A = new Class(variable);
    A->setAutoDelete(true);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(A);

    m_thread_count++;

    if(m_thread_count >0 && m_thread_count %4== 0)
    {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone(); // crashes after all threads finished here
    }
}
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();
```

The crashes happened soon after 4 threads has been executed and ended. I assume the crash happens when QThreadPool tries to delete these threads? Can someone point out if I have done anything wrong here with shared pointers in multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Not enough information to know what you did wrong. Secondly, you should not be counting threads with that global m_thread_count anyway - QThreadPool takes care of this for you. Finally, if you want to know if shared_ptr causes problems, just pass plain pointer in and see if it crashes (for your example, using unique_ptr is probably better anyway).. Good luck.

Comment: why are you calling waitForDone all four iterations? It blocks and destroys the threads. Thread reuse is the main point of using a thread pool at all. Just pass them all to start(), the thread pool will enqueue the runnables.

Comment: After removing the QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone(); in the loop, it crashes even earlier. I managed to bypass many interation sometimes with this condition though. It is not calling waitForDone all four interation. It is stopping too many things lining up in the queue. Many people has suggested not to use this, but it seems to stop some issues for me. That is why I suspect the issue lies within my Class A. Is shared_ptr thread safe at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is *not* thread-safe, as in accessing the *same instance* from multiple threads is not allowed. However, using two different instances of `shared_ptr` that both point to the same object is thread-safe, as long as that object itself is thread-safe. See also [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

So if you store the `shared_ptr` as a reference in `Class`, that might crash. Make a copy of the `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: This applies, in fact, to all implicitly shared classes within Qt as well: all templated containers, `QString`, `QImage`.